# cursor:pointer; not working on a css3 transitioned link

Tags: css, cursor, anchor, css-transitions

I have an odd issue here :http://alarmefast.com/securitasdirect2011/index.php

On the top left corner, I have a link set to `display:block;` containing a `<span>` that I have set to rotate on hover using CSS3 transitions. The odd thing is that it seems to conflict with the cursor displaying as a pointing hand.

Any idea why ?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I'm using Chrome 12 beta on OSX. The little hand appears and then disappears once the animation is complete.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what should be happening and also which browser you have having a problem with? In Chrome 13, when I hover over the facebook logo it spins around and the cursor is the _hand_ icon (pointer) because it is an `<anchor>` tag with an `href` attribute.

Comment: @andyb Indeed, sorry I was a bit hasty in my question. It's updated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in Internet Explorer 8. The problem goes away when I remove the gradient attributes.

Comment: Hm, seeing same issue on Chrome 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its works fine for me in chrome 11 and firefox 4
may be its beta problem

Comment: Yeah that's what I figure... Thanks. Either way not a lot of our users use the chrome12 beta/osx combination anyway.

Comment: Experiencing the issue with Chrome 14/OSX.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this (the bug still exists: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103198), there is a gross hack that helped me.

This bug is fixed by applying ["the magic CSS bullet" that triggers GPU acceleration](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/#toc-hardware-accell) to any element on the page:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

I will leave it up to you to decide whether the associated cons of this technique (like loss of battery life due to using the GPU just to work around a small bug) outweigh the fix.